# PHP Code: usage of this keyword

Tags: php

```
public function __construct($template = '', array $data = array())
{
    if ($template !== '') {
        $this->setTemplate($template);
    }
    if (!empty($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
            $this->$name = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Got this from the devshed composite view tutorial (http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/PHP-Composite-View-Design-Pattern-Introducing-the-Key-Concepts/1/). Anyway, I'm a bit confuse on, `$this->$name = $value;` statement.

I usually use `$this` for class's properties and/or when invoking class's methods within the said class. Plus the statement have two `$`'s. Which is weird! So is `$this->$name = $value` referring to the `$name` defined in the foreach loop? If so can someone explain this usage or logic behind this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $name in

```
$this->$name = $value
```

Sets the variable defined as $name to $value

E.g. if $name = 'user', then this is the equivalent to

```
$this->user = value;
```

This type of syntax is often used (as demonstrated above) in foreach loops to set object values.

Note: Each time $this->variable_name is called, if 'variable_name' is not already defined as a property of the object, the magic __set function is called, with 'variable_name' passed as the argument.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: Here right, but only true, if `name` does not exists as real property. In this case the magic properties are not called.

Comment: @KingCrunch - Yes, this is true, will edit my response to make it a bit clearer

Comment: I think I got it. After messing around with the AbstractView class. It seems that $this->$name is referring to a dynamically created $name by __set. So if say, a class property isn't explicitly define in the class, a user can basically do: $foo = new AbstractView; $foo->bar = 'stuff';, so that the __set function is called and create a bar class property to the abstractview class. And $this->$name = $value statement is referring to the $name variable, a place holder, that is used in the other magic methods defined through out the AbstractView class, hence the extra $. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't go to the link you posted but reading the code.

I will give you an example:

```
// If $data has the following values
array(
    'firstname' => 'my first name',
    'surname'  => 'my surname'
)
```

The code will have 'firstname' and 'surname' as a public property of the class. The values for `$this->firstname` will be 'my first name'. The value of `$this->surname` will be 'my surname'.

Answer (score 0):

$name contain the `name of property` nothing else

instead of just mentioning the property statically it is pointing to the variable which contain the name of property

```
$name='someproperty';

$this->$name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let as assume that the current value of $name is "foo".
then $this->name will return exactly the same as $this->foo.

Comment: You mean `$this->$name`. And not *return*, but rather *refer*.